# How to copy files according to their extensions

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, file-transfer

I have a java project with about 200 modules, as:

```
C:/ROOT1/module1/p1/p2/C1.java
C:/ROOT1/module1/p1/C2.java
C:/ROOT1/module1/R1.properties
C:/ROOT1/module2/p3/p4/C3.java
C:/ROOT1/module3/p4/p5/p6/C4.java
C:/ROOT1/module3/p4/p5/R2.txt
```

now I want to write a windows batch script, so I can copy these files to another location, but maven friendly, so all java files be in `/src/main/java` and all non java files in `/src/main/resources`. So desired file structure will be something like

```
C:/ROOT2/module1/src/main/java/p1/p2/C1.java
C:/ROOT2/module1/src/main/java/p1/C2.java
C:/ROOT2/module1/src/main/resources/R1.properties
C:/ROOT2/module2/src/main/java/p3/p4/C3.java
C:/ROOT2/module3/src/main/java/p4/p5/p6/C4.java
C:/ROOT2/module3/src/main/resources/p4/p5/R2.txt
```

how can I write such batch file for windows to do this?

By the way many of target folders have not been created, the script I need should create proper folders under ROOT2.

Comment: Why not write a Java program for it instead?

Comment: believe me the script I've written below is much simpler and shorter than any java program doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and did this:

```
@echo off
set sourceDir=C:\ROOT1
set destDir=c:\ROOT2

for /D %%i in (%destDir%\*) do (
  rd /s /q "%%i"
)

for /D %%i in (%sourceDir%\*) do (
  robocopy %%i %destDir%\%%~ni%%~xi\src\main\java\ *.java /S /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np > nul
  robocopy %%i %destDir%\%%~ni%%~xi\src\main\resources\ *.* /XF *.java /S /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np > nul
)

echo FINISHED!
```